# Is there a real solution to password encrypting a pdf?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, foxit-reader

I'm trying to make a non-editable pdf using Adobe Acrobat's encryption tool.

However even with 256 bit AES encryption I can still remove the password in five seconds using a free online service.

Is there any pdf encryption software that creates a truly irremovable pdf?

Comment: I think services that remove the password will brute force and try many combinations until they guess the password used. So the time it takes to guess the password should depend on how strong the chosen password is. Are you using a strong password and it still takes 5 seconds to remove it? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_strength

Answer (score 0):

Adding a password just to restrict editing does not actually encrypt a PDF file, which is why that "free online service" works. If you add a separate password that restricts viewing of the file, then the PDF will actually be encrypted.